# What would one consider $\lim_{x \to \infty}(\frac{1}{x}+0^{\frac{1}{x}})$ given $0^0=1$? Is it continuous for $x\gt0$?

Tags: limits, continuity

I had a curious thought cross my mind earlier. Given for the sake of conjecture that $0^0=1$, what would be the value of:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty}{\left(\frac{1}{x}+0^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)}$$

Say this value is equal to $1$. What would be the value of:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty^-}{\left(\frac{1}{x}+0^{\frac{1}{x}}\right)}$$

I don't know if $\lim_{x \to \infty^-}$ is any sort of accepted notation, and if it is used for something else, let me know, but it is the best way I could think of to describe what I'm wondering. Would this limit be equal to $0$ as opposed to the first limit being equal to $1$ (given that it is)?

Another question about this is whether we could consider the equation $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}+0^{\frac{1}{x}}$ to still be continuous for $x\gt0$, or whether this would be considered to have a "discontinuity at infinity".

I just wanted to spark curiosity with what sparked some for me, and also learn a little more about any nuances limits could have like this.

Comment: What is $0^{\frac{1}{x}}$ for any positive $x$?

Comment: @JoshuaWang For any positive $x$, $0^{\frac{1}{x}}$ would be $0$

Comment: So why do you take $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}0^{\frac{1}{x}} = 1$?

Comment: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}$ would be $0$, so $\lim_{x\to\infty}0^{\frac{1}{x}}=0^0=1$

Comment: Careful, direct substitution doesn't always work.

Comment: I see, that's partially why I asked this, because I was curious about what the nuances of something like this would be. That's why I was saying that if $\lim_{x\to\infty}0^{\frac{1}{x}}$ was to be considered $1$, that maybe to the "left" of "directly at infinity", or "$\lim_{x\to\infty^-}0^{\frac{1}{x}}$", it would be $0$. So would we then consider $\lim_{x\to\infty}0^{\frac{1}{x}}$ to be $0$?

Comment: @Brian359: Considering $\lim_{x\to\infty}0^{1/x}$ to be $1$ is rather like considering $1+1$ to be $3$, so we simply don’t do it. That limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of a limit to infinity: $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = L$ means that for all $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x > x_0$, $|f(x) - L| < \epsilon$.

Now, $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty } 0^{1/x} = 0$, since for any $\epsilon > 0$, we can choose $x_0$ to be anything, (I'll choose $x_0 = 1$ arbitrarily). Then, for all $x \in \mathbb{R} , x > 1$, we have $0^{1/x} = 0$.

Then apply the same reasoning for your original problem.